# Void function pointers to modify data in another class

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers, void-pointers

I will do my best to explain this as clearly as possible.

My example currently involves 3 different classes.

1. My model class (lets call it `MyModel.cpp`)
2. My data class that MyModel has an object of (`MyData.cpp`)
3. My undo redo class that modifies my model (`MyModelUR.cpp`)

`MyModel` has a `MyData` object.  `MyData` contains a bunch of doubles each with its own get and set function.  The way my system works is the setter is called by calling `redo()` in `MyModelUR`.  This `redo()` function is called in `MyModel` when a change is detected.  This is outside the scope of the problem though.

`MyModelUR` has 3 functions, a constructor which takes a few args, `undo()` and `redo()` which are NOT allowed to take any args.

What happens is, I want `MyModel` to pass a function pointer of the desired setter in `MyData` to `MyModelUR`.

So, that means the constructor for `MyModelUR` needs to take a function pointer as an arg and then store it in a private global variable.  So far I have something like this...

```
MyModelUR::MyModelUR(MyModel* model, double newValue, void (*function)(double))
{
    Model = model;

    NewValue = newValue;

    //FunctionToCall is a void*
    FunctionToCall = &function;
}
```

Now, in my `redo()` function, I want to use `FunctionToCall`...I'm trying to do this but it's not working and just giving me compiling errors...

```
MyModelUR::redo()
{
    Model->data()->FunctionToCall(NewValue);
}
```

I want to implement it this way so I don't need X number of `undo()`/`redo()` functions for each double in `MyData`.

I appreciate your help and suggestions, but I have a few restrictions when considering replies like, I want to use this architecture due to some other constraints I have, and I can't use Boost libraries.

TLDR; I want to call a void function pointer which takes a double in a separate class that's being called on an object.

Thank you!

EDIT: After the comments below this is what I'm working with...

```
MyModelUR::MyModelUR(MyModel* model, double newValue, void (MyModel::*function)(double)) :
    Model(model),
    NewValue(newValue),
    FunctionToCall(function)
{
}

void MyModelUR::redo()
{
    MyData data = Model->data();

    data.*FunctionToCall(NewValue);
}
```

However, this throws the error on the 2nd line of code in `redo()` that says: "must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in ..."

Comment: "I'm trying to do this but it's not working and just giving me compiling errors"  Please post the errors.

Comment: If you need to support undo you should consider using the "Command" pattern.

Comment: This is essentially a command, just parameterized by method.

Comment: you could also make `MyModelUR` a template over the setter member-function pointer.

Comment: That error is because I missed a parenthesis - it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your function pointer should be a *method* pointer, and you're trying to use a free-function pointer.

Secondly, don't try to store this as a `void*`, it isn't guaranteed to be the same size. Just declare it as a method pointer and stop casting.

Lastly, you're currently storing (in your `void*`) the *address* of the *transient function pointer argument*, which will be invalid even if it were the right type.

Your code should end up something like this:

```
class MyModelUR {
    ...
    MyModel *Model;
    double NewValue;
    void (MyData::*FunctionToCall)(double);
    ...
    MyModelUR(MyModel* model, double newValue, void (MyData::*function)(double))
      : Model(model), NewValue(newValue), FunctionToCall(function)
    {}
    void redo() {
        MyData &data = Model->data();
        (data.*FunctionToCall)(NewValue);
    }
};
```

---

Instantiate one of these like:

```
MyModelUR *ur = new MyModelUR(model, 3.4, &MyData::setSomeValue);
```

---

Functional note: you'll need a getter method pointer and somewhere to store the old value as well, if you want undo.

Aesthetic note: initial uppercase member names are horrible, it's the same scheme you're using for types. Just IMO.

Comment: Awesome!  This has gotten me really far, but I made a mistake in my first post.  MyData isn't a pointer.  So, I'm trying to do something like this (based on your code): Model->data().(*FunctionToCall)(NewValue); and I get weird errors.

Comment: If `MyModel::data()` returns a reference it's pretty similar - I'll edit it in ...

Comment: I had tried what you had before your edit, but I get the error: "must use '.*' or '->' to call pointer-to-member function in..."

Comment: Yea, my redo() looks like this now:  MyData data = Model->data(); data.*FunctionToCall(NewValue); ...this is when I get that error I specified in my previous comment.

Comment: Quick aside: you're taking a value copy of the data object, and not mutating the one in `Model`. Or is the data object a shallow-copy wrapper around the values?

Comment: I didn't fully understand your question...but, my intent is to take the copy of MyData that MyModel has and modify that inside of redo().  In MyModel's header, I have private MyData Data.  The Model will detect this change and then refresh the views.

Comment: How will the model detect that a _copy_ of it's data has been changed? I've used a reference in my updated code, so the data will be mutated in place

Comment: Well, I'm using Qt, so what you can't see in my abridge edition of the code is that the model automatically emits a signal when it's data changes.  I got your example to compile, but I had the remove the ampersand from MyData &data to get it to compile.  I'm doing some testing now to see if it actually works!  Thanks!

Comment: Lastly, I'm trying to now call the constructor in MyModel by trying: new MyModelUR(this, 3.4, MyData::setSomeValue) but it says 'MyData' is not a class or namespace.  I also tried it with MyData.setSomeValue and it still didn't work.

Comment: I owe you a beer my friend!